# How to pass custom model object from razor view to controller action in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing my first production application in mvc 5.  I'm trying to pass a custom object as a parameter to a http post action in my controller.  Basically, I have a view wrapped in my CustomerReport View Model, in that, I have a partial that creates a modal with the option of selecting items from the model and I want to save the selections through a controller action passing the view model (or properties of the view model) as a parameter.

My Report View Model

```
public class CustomerReport
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<NewEnterprise> Enterprises { get; set; }
    public NewEnterpriseRepository EnterpriseRepository { get; set; }
    public NewCustomerRepository CustomerRepository { get; set; }
    public NewProgramRepository ProgramRepository { get; set; }
    public List<NewCustomer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<NewProgram> Programs { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
    public List<ReportSelectionItem> ReportSelectionItems { get; set; }
    public List<ReportSelectionItem> FilteredSelectionItems { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public string ReportType { get; set; }
    public NewReports Reports { get; set; }

    public CustomerReport()
    {
        User = HttpContext.Current.GetUser();
        Enterprises = new List<NewEnterprise>();
        Customers = new List<NewCustomer>();
        Programs = new List<NewProgram>();
        InvoiceItems = new List<InvoiceItem>();
        ReportSelectionItems = new List<ReportSelectionItem>();
    }

    public CustomerReport(User user)
    {
        User = user;
        Enterprises = new List<NewEnterprise>();
        Customers = new List<NewCustomer>();
        Programs = new List<NewProgram>();
        InvoiceItems = new List<InvoiceItem>();
        ReportSelectionItems = new List<ReportSelectionItem>();
        Start = Code.StringExtensions.InputDate(new DateTime(2016, 01, 01)).ToString();
        End = Code.StringExtensions.InputDate(DateTime.Today).ToString();
    }

    public CustomerReport(User user, List<NewEnterprise> enterprises, List<NewCustomer> customers, List<NewProgram> programs)
    {
        User = user;
        Enterprises = enterprises;
        Customers = customers;
        Programs = programs;
    }

    public List<ReportSelectionItem> GetAllReportSelectionItems()
    {
        var items = new List<ReportSelectionItem>();
        foreach (var ent in Enterprises)
        {
            var item = new ReportSelectionItem(ent);
            items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var cust in Customers)
        {
            var item = new ReportSelectionItem(cust);
            items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (var so in Programs)
        {
            var item = new ReportSelectionItem(so);
            items.Add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }

    public List<ReportSelectionItem> ReportSelectionItemsSearch(string search)
    {
        var items = GetAllReportSelectionItems();
        var filteredItems = new List<ReportSelectionItem>();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
        {
            filteredItems = items.Where(i => i.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
            return filteredItems;
        }
        return items;
    }

    public List<ReportSelectionItem> ReportSelectionItemsFilter(List<ReportSelectionItem> items, string type)
    {
        var filteredItems = new List<ReportSelectionItem>();
        if (!type.ToLower().Equals("all"))
        {
            filteredItems = items.Where(i => i.Type.ToLower().Contains(type.ToLower())).ToList();
            return filteredItems;
        }
        return items;
    }

    public void SearchAndFilter(string search, string searchType)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
        {
            this.FilteredSelectionItems = this.ReportSelectionItemsSearch(search);
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchType))
        {
            this.FilteredSelectionItems = this.ReportSelectionItemsFilter(this.ReportSelectionItems, searchType);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSlashFromDates(string start, string end)
    {
        if (start != null)
        {
            this.Start = start.Replace("/", "");
        }
        if (end != null)
        {
            this.End = end.Replace("/", "");
        }
    }
}
```

My class for list of items to select from

```
public class ReportSelectionItem
 {
     public Guid ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string DisplayName { get; set; }
     public string Number { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
     public string TypeDisplay => GetTypeDisplay(Type);
     public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

     public ReportSelectionItem()
     {
         ID = Guid.NewGuid();
         IsSelected = false;
     }

     public ReportSelectionItem(NewEnterprise ent) : this()
     {
         Name = ent.Name;
         DisplayName = ent.DisplayName;
         Number = ent.EnterpriseNumber.ToString();
         Type = ent.GetType().ToString();
     }

     public ReportSelectionItem(NewCustomer cust) : this()
     {
         Name = cust.Name;
         DisplayName = cust.DisplayName;
         Number = cust.Id.ToString();
         Type = cust.GetType().ToString();
     }

     public ReportSelectionItem(NewProgram so) : this()
     {
         Name = so.Description;
         DisplayName = so.DisplayName;
         Number = so.ServiceOrderNumber.ToString();
         Type = so.GetType().ToString();
     }

     public string GetTypeDisplay(string str)
     {
         if (str.ToLower().Contains("enterprise"))
         {
             return "Enterprise";
         }else if (str.ToLower().Contains("customer"))
         {
             return "Customer";
         }else if (str.ToLower().Contains("program"))
         {
             return "Program";
         }
         else return str;
     }
 }
```

A selection of my main view that houses the modal

```
@using System.Activities.Statements
@model RecognitionReports.Web.ViewDataModels.CustomerReport

@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
                <div class="search-form">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("New", "CustomerReports", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <form class="form">
                        <fieldset>
                                @Html.Label("Search:", new { @class = "form-label" })
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Selection Name or ID Number here..." })
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search:</a>
                                                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <li><input name="searchType" type="submit" id="all" value="All" class="form-control btn btn-info" /></li>
                                                        <li><input name="searchType" type="submit" id="ent" value="Enterprise" class="form-control btn btn-info" /></li>
                                                        <li><input name="searchType" type="submit" id="cust" value="Customer" class="form-control btn btn-info" /></li>
                                                        <li><input name="searchType" type="submit" id="so" value="Program" class="form-control btn btn-info" /></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    }
                </div>

            <!-- Report Selection Modal -->
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ReportSelectionOptionsModal", Model);}
            <!-- Report Modal -->
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ReportModal", Model); }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My modal view

```
@model RecognitionReports.Web.ViewDataModels.CustomerReport

<div id="selection-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Report Selection Options</h4>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSelections", "CustomerReports", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
                    <caption>All Report Options: </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Display Name</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Manage</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.FilteredSelectionItems)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>@item.DisplayName</strong></td>
                                <td>@item.TypeDisplay</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsSelected, new { @class = "check-box", Name=item.ID, id=item.ID })
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="action" value="Save"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Possible ways I'd like to pass to the controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSelections(CustomerReport report)
    {
        //make sure selections are saved
        return View("New", report);
    }
```

or

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSelections(List<ReportSelectionItems> items)
    {
        //make sure selections are saved
        return View("New", report);
    }
```

I've tried a lot of things and it continues to pass the parameter as null.  I know that razor turns the object properties into strings after the page renders, but I've seen people pass custom objects as parameters to controller actions... What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to do this?

Edit:  Updated For loop in modal view to:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.FilteredSelectionItems.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
        <td><strong>@Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].DisplayName</strong></td>
        <td>@Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].TypeDisplay</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "check-box", Name = Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].ID, id = Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].ID})
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].ID)
        </td>
    </tr>
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only field that you have in your form is a checkbox for each of the elements in the `FilteredSelectionItems` property. So that's the only information that will make it to your server. You might need to adjust a little bit the form:

Instead of this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.FilteredSelectionItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td><strong>@item.DisplayName</strong></td>
        <td>@item.TypeDisplay</td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(i => item.IsSelected, new { @class = "check-box", Name=item.ID, id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

use this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.FilteredSelectionItems.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td><strong>@item.DisplayName</strong></td>
        <td>@item.TypeDisplay</td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => model.FilteredSelectionItems[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "check-box", Name=item.ID, id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now your controller action will successfully bind to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSelections(CustomerReport report)
{
    // only report.FilteredSelectionItems collection will be available here
    // because that's the only thing you have input fields in the form
    ...
}
```

If you need the other fields populate as well, you could retrieve them from your database, the same way you retrieved them in your GET action. And then merge with the results of the `FilteredSelectionItems` collection that was populated by the user checkbox selections from the view.

Comment: Thank you so much! i've got this mostly working, however, it isn't keeping the selected values when passing to the parameter, i.e., if I check a box and submit, the list passed through does not have any of the IsSelected properties set to true.  I also tried adding a hiddenfor field for the reportSelectionItem ID